# Big Cartel, using a web server to host a custom font not working

Tags: css, webserver, font-face, custom-font, bigcartel

Using @font-face to edit the BigCartel CSS and using a dedicated web server to host the files, still I cannot manage to get my custom font to work. I will attach some pictures for reference. What am I doing wrong? Is my code wrong? Or is BigCartel possibly blocking my font files?

[cPanel File Manager on HostGator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxw0n.png)

[CSS @font-face in BigCartel "Customization"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1O0Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am Big Cartel store developer and designer. I usually upload custom font on GitHub and used in Big Cartel store.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: babelgam;
    src: url(https://gist.githubusercontent.com/majedur-rahaman/bb04ff669fe1f13cb9cf3718f5d3adfc/raw/ddc98c1c070a947d7f43dbd5e94a0fe158669cf9/babelgam.ttf); 
}
```

Use font everywhere you need.

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,
.button,
#error li,
#site_footer ul,
#site_footer #search input,
#main_nav li,
#cart_items li dt,
#cart_items li dd,
#cart_options #cart_discount p,
#cart_summary li span,
.standalone .canvas h1, input,
#cart_items li .quantity_input input
{ font-family:babelgam; }
```